# Split a row in Pandas based on delimiter across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as below with all three columns having strings:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | red, yellow, blue | Texas, California |
| Banana | yellow, orange | Indiana, New Zealand |
| Watermelon | grey |  |

I would like to split each row into multiple rows based on a delimiter value.
The final output would look like below.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | red | Texas |
| Apple | yellow | California |
| Apple | blue |  |
| Banana | yellow | Indiana |
| Banana | orange | New Zealand |
| Watermelon | grey |  |

**Note**:

1. Delimiters would only be present in Column B and Column C.
2. The splits need not be equal. For instance, In row 1, the max splits across Column B and Column C are 3. But since column C has only 2 splits, the third row would result in column C as null/blank.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows) stack overflow post, but couldn't apply it in my case here since each column would have different values based on splits across multiple columns, and since I am dealing with string splits.

Comment: May I know why don't you respond to the below answers posted by users after so much time and effort invested by them?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your strings, then pad the lists in each row so that they all have the same length and finally apply `pd.Series.explode`:

```
df = df.fillna('').set_index('Column A')
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(r'\s*,\s*'))

def pad_lists(row):
    max_len = max(len(x) for x in row)
    return row.apply(lambda x: x + ['']*(max_len-len(x)))

print(df.apply(pad_lists, axis=1).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
     Column A Column B     Column C
0       Apple      red        Texas
1       Apple   yellow   California
2       Apple     blue             
3      Banana   yellow      Indiana
4      Banana   orange  New Zealand
5  Watermelon     grey
```

Edit: setting 'Column A' as index (optionally resetting at the end) to make code less verbose and removing column names (B,C) from code for better generalization

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


tmp = df.set_index('Column A').apply(lambda x: x.str.split(','))
result = (tmp.where(tmp.notnull(), '')
          .apply(lambda x: list(zip_longest(*x)), axis=1)
          .explode()
          .apply(pd.Series)
          .set_axis(tmp.columns, axis=1)
          )
print(result)
>>>
            Column B    Column C
Column A        
Apple       red         Texas
Apple       yellow      California
Apple       blue        None
Banana      yellow      Indiana
Banana      orange      New Zealand
Watermelon  grey        None
```

Comment: Nice use of `zip_longest`! I think you can replace `where(...)` with `fillna('')`. Also `zip_longest` will accept `fillvalue=''` as kwarg.

Comment: @Tranbi, If I set fillvalue = '' in zip_longest, it will prompt the error: 
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: That's... strange. For me your code works with the following lambda function: `lambda x: list(zip_longest(*x, fillvalue=''))`. I use python 3.10.9 and pandas 1.5.3

Comment: I use python 3.8.10 and pandas 1.5.1

Comment: Have you checked for typos? Cause there should be any float object in there...

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1**

We could let pandas concat fill the lengths and then reshape to get the columns with lists filled equally and then explode.

```
list_cols = ["Column B", "Column C"]
df[list_cols] = (
    pd.concat([df[col].str.split("\s*,\s*", expand=True) for col in list_cols])
    .fillna("")
    .agg(list, axis=1)
    .values.reshape(len(df), len(list_cols), order="F")
)
df = df.explode(list_cols, ignore_index=True)
df = df[df[list_cols].ne("").any(axis=1)]
print(df)

     Column A Column B     Column C
0       Apple      red        Texas
1       Apple   yellow   California
2       Apple     blue             
3      Banana   yellow      Indiana
4      Banana   orange  New Zealand
6  WaterMelon     grey
```

**Option 2**

Make columns B, C equal in length by padding with nan and then explode.

```
df["Column B"] = df["Column B"].str.split("\s*,\s*")
df["Column C"] = df["Column C"].str.split("\s*,\s*")
b_len = df["Column B"].str.len()
c_len = df["Column C"].str.len()

to_repeat = list(map(max, zip(b_len, c_len)))

df["Column C"] = df["Column C"] + pd.Series([[np.nan]*r for r in to_repeat - c_len])
df["Column B"] = df["Column B"] + pd.Series([[np.nan]*r for r in to_repeat - b_len])

df = df.explode(["Column B", "Column C"], ignore_index=True).fillna("")
print(df)

     Column A Column B     Column C
0       Apple      red        Texas
1       Apple   yellow   California
2       Apple     blue             
3      Banana   yellow      Indiana
4      Banana   orange  New Zealand
5  WaterMelon     grey
```